# How to parse text into hyperlink with php

Tags: php, string, parsing, url

I am using mysqli queries in php script to pull data from mysql database table and display it on website.

Some of the data includes links, but they are formatted in specific format. The links are formatted as `#Link Name#http://www.link.com`

So first `#` sets the name and the second `#` sets the hyperlink.

I would need my php script to parse this and display as normal hyperlink on a website.

Here is the php scrip:

```
<?php
include('mysql_connection.php');

$c = mysqlConnect();

$locale = $_GET['locale'];
$last_news_id = $_GET['news_id'];

sendQuery ("set character_set_results='utf8'"); 
sendQuery ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'"); 

if (strcmp($locale,"en") != 0)
    $locale = "en";

$result = sendQuery("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id > ".$last_news_id." and locale = '" . $locale . "' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");

echo '<table width=\"100%\">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
{
    echo '<tr><td width=\"100%\"><b>Date: </b>'.$row[2].'</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td width=\"100%\">'.nl2br($row[3]).'</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td width=\"100%\"><hr style="height: 2px; border: none; background: #515151;"></td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

mysqliClose($c);
?>
```

EDIT: I added the line and it sort of helped with one issue:

```
echo '<tr><td width=\"100%\">'.preg_replace('/#([^#]*)#.*/', '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$1</a>', $row[3]).'</td></tr>';
```

It still opens the existing page and not the hyperlink. I guess the $2 should be the hyperlink, the value that goes after second #. However, I'm not totally sure how to code this into php.

Comment: It would make more sense if you reduce the problem in your question. E.g. that the data comes from a database is actually not really of matter. More useful would be that you give example strings that contain the links, what you tried so far to transform those strings (your current code contains *nothing* about that) and then the expected output *for that example string(s)*. The rest is just outputting a string or getting a string which is not what you actually want to ask about. Just focus your question on your problem ;)

Comment: Ok, I edited my original post.

Comment: I am wondering, how does a link with hash portion (`http://example.com/foo#bar`) get stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $row[3] is the data includes links, by using regular expression,

```
preg_replace('/#([^#]*)#(.*)/', '<a href="$2">$1</a>', $row[3]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I replaced the line with: 
echo '<tr><td width=\"100%\">'.preg_replace('/#([^#]*)#.*/', '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$1</a>', $row[3]).'</td></tr>';
Only thing - it still opens the existing page and not the hyperlink. I guess the $2 should be the hyperlink, the value that goes after second #. However, I'm not totally sure how to code this into php.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I didn't add the capture group for $2

Comment: Superb, it works perfectly. You are a really smart and helpful person. I want to upvote you, but the site won't let me. Thanks!!

Comment: The regex should either not catch invalid URL characters -or- deal with them. Additionally, the output (replacement) needs to be properly encoded, too. The current variant is shortsighted and leads to problems. Unfortionatly the OP did not provide any sample data therefore, it's not really promising at the current state to show how this is properly done.

Answer (score 0):

A regex would be better - but you could do it like this:

Assuming your link is '`$row[3]`' and it only contains one just one bit of information in that format '#Link Name#http://www.link.com', beyond that a regex is the way to go.

```
$temp_data = explode("#",$row[3]);
$linkname = $temp_data[1];
$url = $temp_data[2];

echo "<a href='".$url."'>".$linkname."</a>";
```

Comment: Actually row[3] contains a news post with text and only sometimes links in the #link#www.link.com format.